# Why the fragment tab host with intent go to other fragment?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

I am working on a travel planner project.

The structure of my app is like this:

It is a fragment tab host contain 4 tabs. At the second tab, by default it is a JoinFragment , it check whether the user joined a plan. if yes, it will go to the fragment named calenderFragment. if no , then the user will remain in this fragment, that is a available plan listview  , if the user choose a plan, then he joined and go to calenderFragment

So , my implementation is go to joinFragment first , then if user joined plan , then replace the current fragment

```
    Fragment newFragment = new CalendarFragment();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.realtabcontent, newFragment);
    transaction.commit();
```

The problem is , when I switch from second tab to other tab , the other tab content is overlap on the second tab, instead of every thing in second tab should be cleaned.

In my previous project , I use intent and go to other activity instead of fragment. So, would any experience programmer kindly guide me what how can I fix this? Thanks

**Update:**

It is the main structure :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

**Update 2 (Tabhost class):**

```
tabHost = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
tabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("profile").setIndicator("Profile"),ProfileFragment.class, null);
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("calender").setIndicator("calender"), JoinFragment.class,null);
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("social").setIndicator("Social"), SocialFragment.class,null);
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("news").setIndicator("News"), NewsFragment.class,null);
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("setting").setIndicator("Setting"), SettingFragment.class,null);
```

Comment: Can we get your layout.xml?

Comment: Can we look at how you've implemented your tab logic please?

Comment: I haven't worked much with this kind of tabs, but just by reading the code it seems that Android itself places tab content in `@android:id/tabcontent`, while you put your tab into `@+id/realtabcontent`. Or is it one of those things that seem illogical?